# Greedy algorithm implementation, Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, maximize

I need to implement a Haskell function who receives one Int (truck load capacity), and a list of Ints (boxes models that can be loaded on the truck).

To define which box models must be placed preferably in
truck, it's requested that the boxes with greater capacity in
relation to the available space, always be placed first.

The algorithm should return the list of models of boxes to be placed on truck. I have no idea how to program this a functional paradigm :/

```
maximizeLoad 103 [15, 20, 5, 45, 34]
[45, 45, 5, 5]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How would you do it in another language?

Comment: Why isn't the answer `[34, 34, 34]`? Try reading up on the subset sum problem and determining what properties you need your solution to hold first.

Comment: well the problem looks like knapsack (brute-force would be ``maximumBy (compare `on` sum) . filter ((<= 103) . sum) $ subsequences [15,20,5,45,34]``) - but this would not allow picking items more than once

Comment: @RowanBlush sorry, I edited the properties of the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikR find the heavier box. Add (heavierBox % truckCapacity) heavier boxes. Take the largest value less than the rest of this division, and repeat the process. Right?

Comment: If you post working code as part of your question we might be able to help you translate it to Haskell.

Comment: @Carsten - how about for each weight `w` just replicate it  `div 103 w` times in the input list?

Comment: @Carsten i know this, but i don't know the haskell implementation of this! Thank you!

Comment: @BrenoHenrique The "algorithm" you described in the previous comments doesn't always provide the optimal answer. It works only with if the boxes have capacities that at least double each time (BTW: that's why usually coins come in 1 cent, 2 cent, 5 cent, 10 cent, 20 cent, 50 cent, etc.. because in this way you *can* use this naive algorithm to compute the change to give).

Comment: @Bakuriu ok, do you know how to implement this? in haskell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruce force approach with smart filtering

```
maximumLoad n = head 
              . head 
              . group length 
              . last 
              . group sum 
              . filter ((<= n) . sum)
              . map concat 
              . sequence 
              . map (rep n)
              . reverse 
              . sort
        where rep n x = take ((div n x)+1) $ iterate (x:) []
              group f = groupBy ((==) `on` f) . sortBy (comparing f) 

> maximumLoad 103 [15, 20, 5, 45, 34]
[34,34,20,15]
```

**UPDATE** For the greedy algorithm, it will be much simpler.  I think the code is easy to read to describe the algorithm.  Expects reverse sorted input list.

```
maxLoad _ [] = []
maxLoad n (x:xs) | n==0 = []
                 | x <= n = x: maxLoad (n-x) (x:xs)
                 | otherwise = maxLoad n xs

> maxLoad 103 $ reverse $ sort [15, 20, 5, 45, 34]
[45,45,5,5]
```

Comment: but the big boxes have priority to load.

Comment: Isn't this the solution?  If not spec needs to include the trade-off between component size and unfulfilled capacity.

Comment: output should be: 

     maximizeLoad 103 [15, 20, 5, 45, 34]
     [45, 45, 5, 5]

Comment: That's 3 less than 103!  What is the trade-off?  Otherwise, a greedy algorithm will do.  Assume 100 target with `[60, 50]`  should the solution be `[60]` or `[50, 50]`?

Comment: for the [60, 50], algorithm will output [60].

Comment: OK, then you just need a greedy algorithm, should be much simpler than my solution which does exhaustive search.